# Reason to have HTTPS for non-www?

Tags: https, no-www

Is it necessary to have a site answer on HTTPS non-www? Do visitors go there?

Background on why I am asking: I have a client which have bought a new multi-domain certificate for their website. It includes the `www.example` version for multiple different TLDs. The certificate does not include the domains without www so the site won't be accessible without www if the request is on HTTPS.

I have recommended the client to buy a new certificate that include the non-www domain addresses as well but they are hesitant to do so. A new certificate including twice as many domains will cost them quite a lot of money. Free certificates using Let's Encrypt is unfortunately not an option on their server.

- They have been online for 10+ years.
- They've been using HTTPS for both www and non-www before.
- The site has had redirection from non-www to www.
- They don't appear to have any important external links on HTTPS non-www.

Comment: Only somebody with access to the server logs (like you) can answer the question of "do visitors go there"?   Instead of asking us, you should look.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller The site in question has had redirect from `http://a.tld` to `https://a.tld` to `https://www.a.tld`. So I'm having a hard time answering that question. I'm looking for some general input, perhaps some insight new to me.

Comment: Like Stephen I think the order is strange: you should first have assessed if people are coming to the non-www server and then decide which certificates to buy. Also some/many? CA automatically create a certificate with `example.com` as SAN when you buy it for `www.example.com` or the opposite. You may need to shop around CAs. Also "They've been using HTTPS for both www and non-www before" so they have (or had) a certificate for the naked domain also. If they want to keep this access (only up to them and all existing inbound links) they need the appropriate certificate...

Answer (score -1):

TLS/SSL negotiation is between the server and browser. You can redirect non-www at the DNS level but it's easy enough to do this at the server level.

EDIT to be clear: redirecting "at the DNS level", I mean your DNS provider may be able to do an URL redirect through their own internal service. This is not possible through DNS by itself.

Comment: Redirects can't be done at the DNS level.  A CNAME is not a redirect.  You always need a web server running to actually issue the redirect.

Comment: This also doesn't address the question of whether supporting HTTPS redirects for the naked domain is worth it in terms of would commonly be used.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Some DNS providers can do that. Namecheap can. I don't use them for that so I might be misunderstanding but they have an option for it. My answer does answer the question because the question seems to think it's a burden. I'm saying it's easy to do so just do it.

Comment: [Namecheap redirect](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/385/2237/how-do-i-set-up-a-url-redirect-for-a-domain)

Comment: Name cheap runs web servers to do the redirects.  It isn't something you can set in DNS.  But you are correct that you might be able to use a third party such as a donation registrar to host the redirects for you.  I don't know of any domain registrars that can do HTTPS redirects though.  I have seen some relatively expensive paid services that can do it.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller You didn't read the link I provided. I just went to one of our Namecheap accounts, DNS only, and URL redirect is one of the options in the same drop down menu as setting A records, CNAME and everything else.

Comment: Name cheap is lying.   Or rather they are simplifying their UI in a way that disguises what they are actually doing behind the scenes.   Rather than set a "redirect record" what they are actually doing is assigning the DNS record to their own web server and issuing a redirect from a web server.   I assure you that there is no such thing as a "redirect record" in DNS.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller See my edit which may clear up what I was trying to say. I also just set a redirect using namecheap's service and it worked. I see I may have confused you by saying it was DNS doing the work when I meant the DNS provider.

Comment: Much clearer edit.   Can you also address the NEED for such redirects, which is really what they are asking about.